# android webview dynamic content image support

Tags: android, webview

I use `WebView` for displaying dynamic contents which gets loaded from db file . in one db table i have `HTML` code . The `WebView` file couldn't load image contents from saved url .

sample html code :

```
     <!doctype html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/gumby.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
<script src='js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js'></script>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='twelve columns centered  ticket' style='background-color: #ffffff;'><p
                style='text-align: right;direction: rtl;padding: 13px'>
           blah balh blah</p> <img src='img/p20.jpg'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then i load this content from db :

```
answerView.loadData(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("content")), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);`
```

c is a `Cursor` type that definded before ;

the answerView Couldn't SHOW p24.jpg .

sry for my bad english..

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can't work since relative to your WebView there is no directory/file `img/p20.jpg`.

[Please see this answer how to display offline images poperly in webview.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700998/android-display-images-in-webview)

Comment: i have img folder right beside where the code called , also i tried using assets and file:///android_asset in img refrence but that not works too !

and the other problem is i cant use loadDataWithBaseURL() mehthod cuz it conflicts with my db table structure .