# How to load local image in Android WebView

Tags: android, image, webview

I'm trying to load a html string stored in the database which contain a image into a `WebView`. The image is stored in the internal memory. I am giving a reference to the html string.But it doesn't work. Any help?

```
String content="<p>Can we have a rotational" +
    " symmetry of order more than 1 whose angle of rotation is&nbsp;</p>\n" +
    "\n <p>(i)&nbsp;<img alt=\"45\\degree\" src=\"file:///storage/emulated/01484890695248.jpg\" /></p>\n" +
    "\n<p>(ii)&nbsp;<img alt=\"35\\degree\" src=\"file:///storage/emulated/01484890697301.jpg\" /></p>";

WebView00.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html","UTF-8", "");
WebView00.getSettings();
```

Comment: did you add read permission? and also run time permission for API>23

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543349/load-local-html-in-webview?rq=1

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563997/3886504

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try like this

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/image_name.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body> <img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"> </body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lost 3 hours searching the internet.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know the feature.. :(

Comment: how did you define `webView`?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore for Android 11 storage policy.

Answer (score 3):

Put the images in your `assets` folder. Then use the corresponding prefix

```
file:///android_asset/
```

Answer (score 1):

In latest android versions we cant access resources such as `assets` , files from storage. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader is best guide to proceed. `WebViewAssetLoader` and its internal classes helps to access them.

you can check the below sample code.

```
    final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
            .addPathHandler("/assets/", new WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(this)) //****for assets****
            .addPathHandler("/images/", new WebViewAssetLoader.InternalStoragePathHandler(context, getFilesDir()))//****for files****
            .build();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                                          WebResourceRequest request) {
            return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
        }
    });

    String assetsPic = "<img width='42px' height='58px' src='https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/pic.png'/>";
    String storagePic = "<img width='42px' height='58px' src='https://appassets.androidplatform.net/images/pic.jpg'/>";
    webView.loadData(assetsPic+"<br>"+storagePic, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is weird. What's with the "https://appassets.androidplatform.net/" ?  Why the need for this fake website? Why can't it be just `src='/asseets/...` ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader#DEFAULT_DOMAIN()

Comment: Are you saying I can change it? It says "It is used by default unless the user specified a different domain.". So can I use what I wrote instead? Or at least something much shorter that can't go to a real website? But still it doesn't answer why the need for this at all. They could have used something that can't be used for websites...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the file path

```
file:///storage/emulated/01484890695248.jpg
```

would be

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/01484890695248.jpg
```

Thanks @Charuක for the help..